# Error while saving a new node of a speific content type

Tags: nodes

my question is..

I have a business listing content type in my website. When i am creating a new listing i can not save it. It shows error message " Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. "

but when i am editing a old listing, i am able to save it.

Also i am able to create and save nodes of other content types like articles etc.

i am having this problem recently. Previously i was able to add them.

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this and how to solve this.

*-----*
Drupal 7.28
Voting, Fivestar rating and other usual modules

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Comment: Looks like a issue with one of your custom modules, check if you have done something there.

Comment: I think it may be due to special characters in the content while saving like aphastorpe (') or any. Just try with little dummy content without any special characters and clear cache in configuration->development->performance -> Clear All caches.

Comment: My guess would be that you have some inconsistency in your database. If the ID of the node you are trying to insert already exists in a subsidiary table, that might cause this error, for instance.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions..i found out that the filed phone number is causing the problem. If i am providing a phone number then the node is not saved, if empty it does. it gives the following error in the db "Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'field_phone_number_value' at row 1 ...." why does it say the numeric value is out of range?